# Get all topics in c++

Tags: c++, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

is there any way to do something like  "rostopic list" or "rostopic find <msg_type>" NOT in a command line but in a C++ code and get the corresponding topics?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53267/get-all-topics-in-c++/) by [nemo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4038/nemo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, look at the [Master API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_API).

getPublishedTopics or getSystemState should do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-01-13**:
do you have an c++ and/or python example for the command getPublishedTopics??????????